# How to access a key in bigram counter dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, tuples, nltk

**Background:** The following code works to perform a toy example of bigram analysis:

```
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text = "some nice words go here"
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
bi_tokens = bigrams(tokens)

bi_count = {}
for token in bi_tokens:
    if token not in bi_count:
        bi_count[token] = 1
    else:
        bi_count[token] += 1
```

**Output:**

```
 print(bi_count)

 {('go', 'here'): 1,
 ('nice', 'words'): 1,
 ('some', 'nice'): 1,
 ('words', 'go'): 1}
```

**Problem:** I would like to use the `key` name (e.g.`('go', 'here')`) to get the corresponding `value` (e.g. `1`) .

I have tried searching http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=freqdist and also [How to access specific element of dictionary of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772497/how-to-access-specific-element-of-dictionary-of-tuples?rq=1) but I have not been able to find the answer.

**Question:** Is there a way to solve my problem by using an `nltk` method or by any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from nltk import bigrams, word_tokenize
>>> text = "some nice words go here"

# Count no. of ngrams
>>> bigram_counter = Counter(bigrams(word_tokenize(text)))

# Iterate through the ngrams and their counts.
>>> for bg, count in bigram_counter.most_common():
...     print(bg, count)
... 
('some', 'nice') 1
('go', 'here') 1
('words', 'go') 1
('nice', 'words') 1
```

**Answer:**

```
# Access the Counter object. 
>>> bigram_counter[('some', 'nice')]
1
>>> bigram_counter[('words', 'go')]
1
```

Take a look at

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm
- https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
search_key = ('go', 'here')
for key, value in bi_count.items(): 
    if key == search_key:
        print(value) #1
```